# Why isn't this column being added in psql?

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I'm following this book and on p.219 I run into an issue where I get an error that the "profile" column isn't being added.

https://pragprog.com/titles/dswdcloj3/web-development-with-clojure-third-edition/

I'm trying to just run it with the source-code (the guestbook-profile files), and I can't get it to work so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I do the following command:

```
(get-user* {:login "testuser"})
```

and get the error:

```
Execution error (PSQLException) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl/receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553).
ERROR: column "profile" does not exist
  Position: 27
```

I looked at the guestbook database, and the user table, and it's true that there is no profile column. But there are files in resources>migrations that add a profile column:

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ADD COLUMN profile JSONB DEFAULT '{}'::JSONB;
```

and in the sql queries file it has code for the profiles:

```
-- START:profile
-- :name set-profile-for-user*  :<! :1
-- :doc sets a profile map for the specified user
UPDATE users
SET profile = :profile
where :login = login
RETURNING *;

-- :name get-user* :? :1
-- :doc gets a user's publicly available information
SELECT login, created_at, profile from users
WHERE login = :login
-- END:profile
```

Please tell me what other information to share. Why isn't the profile column being added? How do I fix this?

EDIT: I just typed the following into a psql command line:

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ADD COLUMN profile JSONB DEFAULT '{}'::JSONB;
```

And now things seem to be working ok. Is this normal to just have to use the command line? Or is it more typical to just have the commands in the resources folder? If so, why didn't mine work? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you did not run the database migrations step?

Comment: Thanks for responding Sean. In the user namespace I first did (start) and then (migrate). Sometimes errors show up, because it will say certain columns already exist, and I ignore those, assuming it will add the columns that don't exist yet.

Comment: If I use the source code, can I use the migrations that are already in the resources folder or do I have to create new ones?

Comment: What library do you use to run the migrations? It's very unlikely a migration will run fine if there are errors.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm using Migratus.